# What is the purpose of Custom File System Provider?

Tags: java, java-7

i'm looking for an example for Custom File System Provider,PLease provide a example or link i can go through.

Answer (score 4):

In operating systems like UNIX you can mount various devices in your file system. There are virtual file systems like `/proc`, `/dev`, network file systems, file system backed by SSH (`sshfs`), etc. This gives users familiar and homogenous way to access information.

Now apply this to Java. You can write file system provider to access any data/information/system. Users familiar with file API can *connect* to various files/systems/devices using known and easy-to-use API. Not to mention single URI can now be used to locate resources on various different devices.

For example check out [Zip File System Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html).